# Application of Python Alternating Conditional Expectation (ACE) algorithm

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to apply the ACE algorithm outlined here: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ace/0.3

Here is the code from the sample page, which works:

```
from ace.samples import wang04
x, y = wang04.build_sample_ace_problem_wang04(N=200)

from ace import model
myace = model.Model()
myace.build_model_from_xy(x, y)
```

Here is the code that I am trying to run:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from ace import model

filename = 'G_perm.txt'

well = pd.read_csv(filename, sep="\s+", error_bad_lines=False)
well.columns = ["k", "por"]

x = np.zeros(len(well))
y = np.zeros(len(well))

for i in range(len(well)):
    x[i] = well.k[i] 
    y[i] = well.por[i]

myace = model.Model()
myace.build_model_from_xy(x, y)
```

Here is a sample of the txt file, with 162 lines:

```
k       por
306.0   26.3
61.0    25.4
1059.0  30.9
1120.0  30.0
540.0   29.8
272.0   27.0
430.0   28.3
84.0    25.6
788.0   30.2
490.0   28.7
541.0   28.8
```

When I try running the code, I get `list index out of range` 
Has anyone implemented ACE successfully with Pandas and Numpy?

Comment: Why not just `x = well.k` and `y = well.por`?

Comment: Yes, that works too. I still have trouble getting ACE to work, though.

Comment: Did the answer solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, it did. One issue I am still having is how to evaluate values that are outside the original x-values. i.e. `myace.eval([200])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `x_values` argument for `build_model_from_xy` appears to require an iterator, as if it is iterating through the list of x variables.  So, the following replacement for your last line should work:

```
myace.build_model_from_xy([x], y)
```

Note that the x from the sample code (`wang04.build_sample_ace_problem_wang04(N=200)`) is, in fact, a list of arrays.